# Как пролистать Panel через невидимый AutoScroll кнопкой?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как при нажатии на кнопку `> button >`, передвинуть ползунок на невидимом `AutoScroll` в конец всей `Panel`?

Если `AutoScroll` сделать невидимым - `False` то прокрутка не работает, не проматывает...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = panel1.HorizontalScroll.Minimum;
        panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = panel1.HorizontalScroll.Minimum;
    }
```

Приведенный код работает только для видимого `AutoScroll`

Comment: без `AutoScroll` только ручное позиционирование контента

Comment: Автоскролл не может быть невидимым: он либо есть, либо его нет. | Возьмите просто TabControl и задайте свойство Alignment = Bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если очень хочется применить именно Scroll, то можно поступить так:

Cоздадим панель (названа `contentPanel`) с содержимым (кнопками), у которой включен `AutoScroll`. Она вложена в панель-обёртку (названа `wrapperPanel`), которая по высоте меньше, из-за чего не видно полосу прокрутки вложенной панели.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            Width = 400;

            var wrapperPanel = new Panel { Parent = this, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, Width = 320, Height = 40 };
            var contentPanel = new Panel { Parent = wrapperPanel, Width = 320, AutoScroll = true };

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                new Button { Parent = contentPanel, Text = i.ToString(), Left = i * 80, TabStop = false };

            var leftButton = new Button { Parent = this, Text = "<<", Top = 80, Left = 20 };
            var rightButton = new Button { Parent = this, Text = ">>", Top = 80, Left = 200 };

            leftButton.Click += (s, e) => contentPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);
            rightButton.Click += (s, e) => contentPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(contentPanel.HorizontalScroll.Maximum, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Задание значения свойству `HorizontalScroll.Value` работает как-то странно (срабатывает не с первого раза), поэтому применил `AutoScrollPosition`.

Конечно, можно скрыть полосу прокрутки и другим способом, например, поместив поверх него пустую панель цвета фона и без рамки.

Обратите внимание на свойство `TabStop` у вложенных контролов (кнопок): я задал ему значение `false`, потому что в противном случае фокус будет перемещаться на них при нажатии клавиши <kbd>TAB</kbd>, в результате панель будет скроллиться (если это вас устраивает, то можете это убрать).

PS: лично я, как кнопкодав, а не мышевод, за отключенную возможность навигации табом с клавиатуры, буду проклинать разрабов... Но в данном примере я просто показал, что автоскролл может реагировать на те действия пользователя, о которых первоначально не подозревали. Так, к сведению.

Comment: Спасибо, что уделили время, пусть даже будет панель в панели, главное результат. Проблема в том, что нельзя управлять настройками сразу в нескольких окнах, поэтому пришлось придумать перемотку, чтобы оставаться в одном окне приложения (она же `FormMain.cs`)

Comment: @Vitokhv - я для чего про `TabStop` расписывал? Сейчас UX вашего дизайна отвратителен. При включенном `TabStop` будут выползать контролы другого _окна_ при нажатии `Tab`. При отключенном, пользователи не смогут выполнять навигацию с помощью `Tab`, что очень удобно.

Comment: @Vitokhv - Как я уже ранее предлагал, возьмите для своей цели компонент `TabControl` - и размещайте на его вкладках настройки разных _окон_. Заголовок табконтрола можно при желании спрятать. Или возьмите просто несколько панелей (`Panel`) и разместите их стопкой друг над другом, пряча ненужные, показывая лишь одну. При этом навигация с помощью `Tab` будет нормальной.

Comment: Про `TabStop` я же понял, это ведь отдельная тема. Для навигации я всегда проверяю `TabStop` под каким номером должны выделяться кнопки навигации. Для двух `Panel` я отключил `TabStop`